# Get data to dataGrid from mysql

Tags: mysql, wpf, vb.net, datagrid

How do i add data to dataGrid view in VB.net (I'm using WPF dataGrid).
Here is a code that works, this code is for login, my application can access database and i can manipulate data:

```
Public Function login(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String)
        Try
            ManageConnection(False) 'Open connection'

            Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM `dbns`.`wrks` WHERE `username` = '" + username + "' and password = '" + password + "'"
            Dim SqlCmd As New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)
            Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()

            If reader.HasRows Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
            reader.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.ToString())
        Finally
            ManageConnection(True)
        End Try
        Return False
    End Function
```

How would i implement a `SELECT * FROM xxxxx WHERE xxxx` and populate

`<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="376,167,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="100" Width="645"/>`

This is my Sub for opening and closing connection:

```
 Public Sub ManageConnection(ByVal CloseConnection As Boolean)
        Try
            'Pripremanje konekcije i upita'
            dbCon = New MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;password=*****;database=****")
            If CloseConnection = False Then
                If dbCon.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then _
                    dbCon.Open()
            Else
                dbCon.Close()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Nije moguća konekcija na udaljenu bazu podataka, koristi drugu opciju.")
        End Try

    End Sub
```

I want to know if i can use my existing function for connecting to database for datagrid specific needs. 
In example:

```
Public Function testniQuery()
        Dim queryString As String =
  "SELECT * FROM table"
        Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(
          queryString, connection)

        Dim customers As DataSet = New DataSet
        adapter.Fill(customers, "Customers")

    End Function
```

Comment: Use parameters and SqlDataAdapter

Comment: Can I reuse my existing code for the query above, especialy function which is opening and closing connection to database?
And can you please give me an example based on my code above, or at least a part of example so i know where to start from @apomene

Comment: There exist plenty of examples and tutorials on the web. E.g. check this [tutorial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-data-adapter.html) from official mysql .net connector site.

Comment: I want to know if i can use my existing connection Public Sub to which i send boolean value for each of cases (TRUE for close and FALSE to open connection) or i need to define connection parameters again to use it in  `Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter( _  
  queryString, connection)  ` @AlexB.

Comment: It´s not worth caching and reusing a single connection - it has too many drawbacks and too little benefits. There are some answers here at SO regarding that topic. You should create one isolated connection for each query/DataAdapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know Visual Basic that well because I work with C# but the Common Library Runtime (CLR) makes it easier to understand both languages.

When you are connected to MySQL, run your query which you will  use *DataAdapter to get the data from the query*.
The result of the query can be saved in a DataTable and you can easily bind the DataTable to the DataGrid.

So, you run one query and you can use that table persistently in your code.

I do this is C#.
**Please bear with C# code. This is a method that will do it**

```
public DataTable Login(string username, string password){
//"SELECT * FROM `dbns`.`wrks` WHERE `username` = '" + username + "' and password = '" + password + "'"
    string query = "SELECT * FROM wrks WHERE username = @username AND password = @password";
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    using (MySQlConnection connection = new MySQlConnection(connectionString))
    {
         using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
    {
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
            adapter.Fill(table);
            return table;
        }
    }
}
```

The DataTable returned can then be binded to the DataGrid as shown below:

```
dataGrid1.DataSource = Login("username", "password").DefaultView;
dataGrid1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I'll start researching starting from this